How to install JDK 22 in Termux
Is it possible to install JDK 22 in Termux?
I already tried to install from source code, but it requires Boot-JDK.
Only JDK 17 is available through the package manager, but I need a version higher than 17.
pkg install openjdk-17
If this is possible how can I install this?

Why do you want to do this? For actual linux, you can just download and unzip the binary archive, but I don't think termux is quite the same and the packages need to be built to target it. So you either need to build it yourself, or find somebody who has built it for you. I don't use termux though so I could be mistaken.

Why do you want to install a short term version of the JDK lie JDK 22?
